# Is zeromq slower than wcf?

Tags: wcf, zeromq

I was testing two client server configurations(ZeroMQ and WCF). Strangely, i found that wcf is faster than zeromq! Its my code or is the net binding so overheaded (since the zeromq must be realy fast from what i am reading)?

Answer (score 2):

what binding ?

i would really like to see your numbers and your code, because we have been using WCF ever since it was still called indigo and it was never very fast, especially when we compared it to zeromq recently, which is in a league of its own. but the speed depends very much on the binding you use. Http is obviously much slower than some of the others.

Comment: the binding is obviously net.tcp in order to get a "correcter" result. Because wcf is serializing object i though it would be good to test it with a simple Customer Class(Id,Name,BirthDate). In zeromq have tested the binaryserializer of .net but it was very slow. So i decided to use the protobuf-net serializer since everyone saying that its realy fast. The result was for binaryserializer on par and a little worst than wcf, and with protobuf-net faster than wcf 20% or so, but not a huge difference. Maybe its the code?

Comment: Well that could be right, depends on the code, but micro benchmarks like this are unreliable. 
Apart from this though, the main advantages come from all the stuff that is NOT in zeromq, which wcf requires/offers. In my experience WCF creates more problems than it solves and does not really make it any easier to write distributed code.
That said when you encapsulate your communication code, it should not be too difficult to switch it out.